# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors without evaluating the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let  $v=(1,2,4,-3)$ and $A=v^t\cdot v$
>   find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors without evaluating $A$ explicitly.

We know that $det(AB)\leq min(det(A),det(B))$ therefore $det(A)=1$ and Therefore the matrix is non-invertible, there is $\lambda=0$ and $Null(A)=3$.

So we have $\lambda=0$ with geometric multiply of $3$

Are those all the eigenvalues? How can we find the eigenvectors without evaluating $A$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Rank one projections like this are extremely easy to analyze. Consider $v^t$ and the three vectors orthogonal to $v$.